# Python Custom Tkinter Status Bar mid function update not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I have created a very simple Tkinter application which has button which calls back a function which calls an API 3 times with different endpoints each time, due to which it takes time.
It works as expected in terms of back-end working, but I have created a status bar through which I want to give update at what stage the application is running at.
The problem I am facing is when the application is initiated it gives correct Status message, and when the loop is completed it gives the confirmation status message.
But, during the loop it does not update the status message as shown in the code below, I have set it to update on each loops iteration.

Moreover sometimes the Tkinter application goes into the not responding mode even though I can see the code running and giving output in the terminal.

```
def automate2():
    tt_codes = []
    exchanges = []
    contract_finals = []
    account_ids = []
    button.configure(state='disabled')
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        tt_code = row['TT_Code']
        exchange = row['TT_Exchange']
        contract_final = row['Contract Final']
        account_id = row['Account ID']
        tt_codes.append(tt_code)
        exchanges.append(exchange)
        contract_finals.append(contract_final)
        account_ids.append(account_id)
        status.set(f"Processing {row} out of {len(df.index)}")
    for i in range(len(tt_codes)):
        target = exchanges[i]
        prod_name = tt_codes[i]
        contract = contract_finals[i]
        markets()
        found_market_id = find_market_id(target)
        products(found_market_id)
        found_product_id = find_product_id(prod_name)
        found_family_id = find_family_id(prod_name)
        instruments(found_product_id)
        found_instrument_name = find_instrument_name(prod_name, contract)
        found_instrument_id = find_instrument_id(prod_name, contract)
        set_limits(found_instrument_name, found_market_id, found_family_id, found_product_id, found_instrument_id, symbol=prod_name, account_id = 1243179)
        status.set(f"Limits have been successfully applied to User {account_id} for product {found_instrument_name}")
    status.set("Done... Please Close the Application")
    showinfo(message = "The process is completed")

def update():
    status.set("Processing Please Wait..........")

def automate():
    update()
    automate2()

app = ctk.CTk()
app.title("Expiry Automation")
app.geometry("550x250")
status = StringVar()
status.set("Click Execute After Updating Files")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
font_head = ctk.CTkFont(family = "Arial")
label_automation = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text = "Expiry Automation update the Excel file with Expiry at this location:", font = font_head)
label_automation.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", padx = 10, pady = 10)
button = ctk.CTkButton(app, text = "Execute", command = automate)
button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 125, pady = 50, sticky = "ew")
status_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, textvariable=status, fg_color="transparent",corner_radius = 30,width = 540,height = 20,font = ("Helvetica", 14),anchor = 'center')
status_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10,sticky="nsew")
app.mainloop()
```

I asked chatGPT, according to the bot, it suggested creating 2 different function: first one to update the status message, second one to run the loop
I tried that but it still skips the first function and directly runs the loop without updating the status message

Even if the status message update once after clicking the button would do the work saying the Code is running and the process has started and application has not crashed.

If possible I request help in preventing the application from to not show "Not Responding" until unless it has really crashed.

Comment: tkinter `mainloop()` handle those pending updates after `animate()` function exits, so during the function execution, no update will be seem.  Also avoid running long loop in a GUI application. Run the long loop in a thread instead.